# urlparse doesn't return params for custom schema

Tags: python, url, uri, urlparse

I am trying to use urlparse Python library to parse some custom URIs.

I noticed that for some well-known schemes `params` are parsed correctly:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse("http://some.domain/some/nested/endpoint;param1=value1;param2=othervalue2?query1=val1&query2=val2#fragment")
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='some.domain', path='/some/nested/endpoint', params='param1=value1;param2=othervalue2', query='query1=val1&query2=val2', fragment='fragment')
>>> urlparse("ftp://some.domain/some/nested/endpoint;param1=value1;param2=othervalue2?query1=val1&query2=val2#fragment")
ParseResult(scheme='ftp', netloc='some.domain', path='/some/nested/endpoint', params='param1=value1;param2=othervalue2', query='query1=val1&query2=val2', fragment='fragment')
```

...but for custom ones - they are not. `params` field remains empty. Instead, params are treated as a part of `path`:

```
>>> urlparse("scheme://some.domain/some/nested/endpoint;param1=value1;param2=othervalue2?query1=val1&query2=val2#fragment")
ParseResult(scheme='scheme', netloc='some.domain', path='/some/nested/endpoint;param1=value1;param2=othervalue2', params='', query='query1=val1&query2=val2', fragment='fragment')
```

Why there is a difference in parsing depending on schema? How can I parse params within `urlparse` library using custom schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `urlparse` assumes that only a set of schemes will uses parameters in their URL format. You can see that check with in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L395-L398).

```
if scheme in uses_params and ';' in url:
        url, params = _splitparams(url)
    else:
        params = ''
```

Which means `urlparse` will attempt to parse parameters only if the scheme is in [`uses_params` (which is a list of known schemes)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L58).

```
uses_params = ['', 'ftp', 'hdl', 'prospero', 'http', 'imap',
               'https', 'shttp', 'rtsp', 'rtspu', 'sip', 'sips',
               'mms', 'sftp', 'tel']
```

So to get the expected output you can  append your custom scheme into `uses_params` list and perform the `urlparse` call again.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import uses_params, urlparse
>>>
>>> uses_params.append('scheme')
>>> urlparse("scheme://some.domain/some/nested/endpoint;param1=value1;param2=othervalue2?query1=val1&query2=val2#fragment")
ParseResult(scheme='scheme', netloc='some.domain', path='/some/nested/endpoint', params='param1=value1;param2=othervalue2', query='query1=val1&query2=val2', fragment='fragment')
```

Comment: Thank you for precise answer. Your solution would do the job but to be honest I don't really feel that modifying library internals that aren't described by the API would be a  proper design pattern. Potentially, this approach could change behavior of other libraries that depend on urlparse. I think that eventually I'll end up with splitting parameters manually.

Comment: @KonradSikorski I agree, the `urlparse` API designed in that way!

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove that custom schemes from the url?
That allways will return the params

```py
urlparse("//some.domain/some/nested/endpoint;param1=value1;param2=othervalue2?query1=val1&query2=val2#fragment")
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='some.domain', path='/some/nested/endpoint', params='param1=value1;param2=othervalue2', query='query1=val1&query2=val2', fragment='fragment')
```